# ColumnSeries Style and Layout WPF Chart Control

Tags: wpf, charts

I'm using a chart and column series in the WPF toolkit to display a value for each month of the year.  Everything is working good and the chart loads except it looks like junk since the series labels on the X axis are all overlapping and I cannot figure out how to get the sizing correct.  When using the lineseries the chart seems to size perfect.

```
                    <DVC:Chart Name="accountChart" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,15,0,0" >
                            <DVC:Chart.Series>
                                <DVC:ColumnSeries Title=" Actual" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Month}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Amt}" Padding="10"/>
                            </DVC:Chart.Series>
                    </DVC:Chart>
```